# moving pipe around corner

Tags: geometry

I worked at some problem with moving pipe around a corner and i was trying to fing the maximum length of pipe for corner with corridor lengths 1. It is pretty obvious that maximum length is ${\sqrt 2}$, since that is the length of pipe when it's in position, when the angles where it touches the outer walls are the same - $45$ degree.

It's obvious that if pipe can get through this point, it can move around the corner. But i don't know how to exactly mathematically prove it.

Comment: Note that the generalization of this question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_sofa_problem seems to be quite difficult.

Comment: You can try to use the symmetry to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this diagram, we see that for a given angle of $\theta$, the largest pipe that can fit at the corner at that angle has length

$$L=\sec\theta+\csc\theta$$

[image]

The largest pipe that can fit around the corner must fit for all angles $\theta$, thus the minimum value of $L$ is the maximum length of pipe that will go around the corner. We use the derivative to find the appropriate value of $\theta$:

$$\begin{align}
L'&=\sec\theta\tan\theta-\csc\theta\cot\theta \\[2 ex]
 &= \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}
\end{align}$$

Setting that equal to zero and solving,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta} &= 0 \\[2 ex]
\sin^3\theta-\cos^3\theta &=0 \\[2 ex]
\frac{\sin^3\theta}{\cos^3\theta} &=1 \\[2 ex]
\tan^3\theta &= 1\\[2 ex]
\tan\theta &= 1\\[2 ex]
\theta &=45°
\end{align}$$

You can easily use the first derivative or second derivative test to see that the minimum value of $L$ is indeed at that angle.